# Emacs-like line navigation in gedit

Tags: emacs, text-editor, gedit, gedit-plugin

I have been using Emacs for the past few months and I like its line navigation feature a lot as it doesn't need you to use arrow keys.

Emacs Line Navigation:

```
C-p : go to previous line
C-n : go to next line
C-f : go forward one character
C-b : go backward one character
```

Is there anyway I can use this in gedit text editor 3 also? Is there any plugin or option for this functionality?